# Skype 4.1 keeps crashing on Ubuntu 12.10!

Tags: skype

I have installed Ubuntu 12.10 recently and also downloaded Skype 4.1 (Ubuntu 12.04 multiarch).
I installed it but every time I have a conversation, or a call, it crashes.

Does anybody know why this happens??

I have also tried to install the Skype version Ubuntu 10.04 32bit, but the same thing happens.
Also I have uninstalled and installed again more than 2 for each one, and restarted the laptop in between.

Please help me!!
I really need skype!!

Comment: Yeah, this is pretty normal. Skype for Linux is crashy; 12.10 is crashy. Putting them together and not expecting crashes just doesn't make sense. Sorry. :(

Comment: I recommend [reporting this as a bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs). ([This question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) also has some good information about bug reporting.) This will probably be closed as off-topic, in accordance with [the FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq) and [this policy](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/228/22949).

Answer (score 1):

Unninstall Skype and remove the Skype ppa from **Software Sources** then install Skype from the normal repositories.

1. Open **Software Sources** or open **Update Manager** and select **Settings**.
2. Under the **Other Software** tab look for the Skype repositories and delete them.
3. Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) and type `sudo apt-get update`
4. Open **Ubuntu Software Center** and search for Skype. Click **Install**.

Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

I recieved some advise today on installing a different and older version of skype.
Which so far works well.

The link for that version is:

http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/mint_import/nadia/import/base/skype

Thanks guys!!

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.hecticgeek.com/2012/01/how-to-remove-pulseaudio-use-alsa-ubuntu-linux/

Above worked for me; no need to reboot after installing the sound mixer.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Skype doesn't work well on any Linux distro I have tried. I had the same problems as you and tried to install with `apt-get` and `yum`; manually download and install the package, then purge it; add repositories and do the same; install old versions; use WINE, etc..

Remember: it's a Microsoft product now. They'll make whatever they can (without making it too obvious) to make you believe their system is better (because it is inherently more compatible with their products). As you, I really need Skype; so I have a virtual machine with Windows (it's way easier than it was for me to try tweaking Skype for Linux so it could work) for Windows programs.